# How to reliably drop records from Guava LoadingCache?

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, guava, google-guava-cache

I am using Guava `LoadingCache` to populate some data into it and I want to remove all the entries from that `LoadingCache` every 1 minute.

```
public class MetricHolder {
  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
  private final LoadingCache<String, AtomicLongMap<String>> clientIdMetricCounterCache =
      CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
          .removalListener(RemovalListeners.asynchronous(new SendToDatabase(), executor))
          .build(new CacheLoader<String, AtomicLongMap<String>>() {
            @Override
            public AtomicLongMap<String> load(String key) throws Exception {
              return AtomicLongMap.create();
            }
          });

  private static class Holder {
    private static final MetricHolder INSTANCE = new MetricHolder();
  }

  public static MetricHolder getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private MetricHolder() {}

  public void increment(String clientId, String name) throws ExecutionException {
    clientIdMetricCounterCache.get(clientId).incrementAndGet(name);
  }

  public LoadingCache<String, AtomicLongMap<String>> getClientIdMetricCounterCache() {
    return clientIdMetricCounterCache;
  }

  private static class SendToDatabase implements RemovalListener<String, AtomicLongMap<String>> {
    @Override
    public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<String, AtomicLongMap<String>> notification) {
      String key = notification.getKey();
      AtomicLongMap<String> value = notification.getValue();
      System.out.println(key);
      System.out.println(value);
      // sending these key/value to some other system

    }
  }
}
```

I am calling `increment` method from lot of different places in the code in a multithreaded way. So for a period of 1 minute it will populate lot of metrics in `clientIdMetricCounterCache`. Now I want to drop all those metrics **reliably** after every 1 minute and send all those metrics to database.

In my case, sometimes write to `increment` method might be very slow but still I want to drop all those entries every 1 minute and I am not doing any read at all on this cache, just writing to it and then dropping those records by sending to some other system. Below is what I saw in the Guava [wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained)

> Caches built with CacheBuilder do not perform cleanup and evict values
>   "automatically," or instantly after a value expires, or anything of
>   the sort. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance during
>   write operations, or during occasional read operations if writes are
>   rare.

So how does `expireAfterWrite` works? Does it work like a scheduler which will run every 1 minute and delete all the entries whatever is there in `clientIdMetricCounterCache` and then again it will wake up after 1 minute and delete all the entries from the same cache and keep going like that? After reading the wiki, I doubt it works like that. If it doesn't, then how can I reliably drop those records every 1 minute and send to some other system as my writes can be rare for some time?

Looks like I may have to use `Guava TimeLimiter` interface and `SimpleTimeLimiter` or may be `ScheduledExecutorService` to reliably timeout the call and then drop the entries? If yes, can anyone provide an example how will this work in my current example?

Comment: I don't see how `TimeLimiter` has to do with anything, but the documentation you quoted clearly answers the question: create a background thread that calls `Cache.cleanUp()` at regular intervals.

Comment: It's worth noting that since you're *modifying* the cached values rather than replacing them, you may lose a concurrent update in your removal listener if another thread has a reference to the `AtomicLongMap` you're trying to clean.

Comment: @shmosel Yeah I saw that in the wiki. The confusion I have is what  I am supposed to do in my background thread? Just call `Cache.cleanUp()` meaning `clientIdMetricCounterCache.cleanUp()` at regular intervals? If you can provide an example, then this will clear my confusion.

Comment: @shmosel Where do you see that that I am modifying the values instead of replacing them?

Comment: Every time you call `incrementAndGet()`.

Comment: So let's say I am calling `increment` method 100 times with `clientId` as `abc` and `name` as `processA`. Then my cache will have `abc` string as the key and its value will be `AtomicLongMap` which will have `processA` as `100` times. Right? This is what my increment method doing. So you are saying that is not the right way as it can lose some concurrent update?

Comment: Right, because another can get the reference before the cleanup and update afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it looks like you're misusing the cache, where a Map would do. You're using no expiration, no size limit, *no caching*, you're just gathering stats.

About the only feature you're using is the loading aspect, and that's not really worth it.

I'd suggest to use an `AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLongMap>>` instead:

- When updating, you get the version for the current minute via `AtomicReference::get`.
- Using the `clientId`, you look up an `AtomicLongMap` in your `ConcurrentHashMap` and create a new one if not found (use `putIfAbsent` on Java 7 or `computeIfAbsent` on Java 8).
- Using the `name`, you update the `AtomicLongMap` just like you posted.
- Once per minute you replace everything via `AtomicReference::getAndSet`.

With the replacement, you can be sure that your stats don't interfere, however, you should wait a bit after `getAndSet` as there may be threads who just obtained the reference and are about to write.

It will produce more garbage than the original approach, but all the garbage will be short living, so you might actually make the GC more happy.

It's simple and need no deep knowledge of a library or its implementation details.

---

I guess, `volatile` instead of `AtomicReference` would also do.

Comment: Do I have to use `AtomicReference` or `volatile` here? If I just have this and populate into this map from multiple threads, then will there be any problem? `ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLongMap<String>> clientIdMetricCounterCache = Maps
      .newConcurrentMap();`

Comment: @david My idea was to replace the map by a new one once per minute. This idea is orthogonal to the part of using a map instead of a cache. So sure, it can work without replacing the map, it just may the periodic operation more complicated (as it probably needs to remove entries while normal operations add and use them).